# How does print() in Python work on the hardware level?

Tags: python, function, printing, hardware, low-level

I'm seeking an in-depth explanation of the `print()` function's operation at the hardware level, specifically within the context of Python. When executing a simple Python command like `print("Hello, World!")`, what are the underlying processes that lead to the text being displayed on the screen?

I've conducted some research, but I found information only about the `printf()` function in C, or explanations focusing on internal function mechanics rather than actual text output. What are some insights into the step-by-step hardware interaction during the `print()` function execution?

Comment: [See built in functions](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e9d1360c9a1072aa23950b321491dc542c3a19b8/Doc/library/functions.rst#id93:~:text=function%3A%3A%20print(*objects%2C%20sep%3D%27%20%27%2C%20end%3D%27%5Cn%27%2C%20file%3DNone%2C%20flush%3DFalse))

Comment: Also built in functions are defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e9d1360c9a1072aa23950b321491dc542c3a19b8/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2026)

Comment: @Daviid Thank you very much, I didn’t know about such a resource!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sends text to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) which is one of two streams handled by the operating system (the other one, [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)), is for errors).

The Python interpreter, which is written in C, is the layer responsible for handling this. You should look at how streams as implemented in C to know how it is handled in the hardware level.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, I’ll know what to ask and find out!

Comment: Look, I noticed a typo in your answer "...which is one of two steams... (should be streams)". And perhaps instead of “It prints to stdout” it is worth replacing with “It sends text to stdout”, because this way the question “How does it print to stdout?” does not arise. I don’t know if it’s possible to give such comments, because I don’t write them often, but I thought it necessary to notify you about this

Comment: Answer updated, thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score 0):

In Python, standard output (often abbreviated as stdout) is the default destination for output generated by your program. Using the print() function without specifying a file or device sends the output to stdout, which is usually your console or terminal.
Python's print() function sends data to standard output by default, but you can also specify a different output destination using the file parameter. For example, you can send output to a file or a different device.
Python opens a file named ‘output.txt’ in write mode, and then we use the print() function to write ‘Hello, World!’ to the file. The print() function interacts with standard output and other output destinations flexibly, making it a powerful tool for displaying and storing your data.

Comment: Is there is any problem with this answer

Comment: @Marwin Rabi, I preferred the answer from Reida Bourial because it has deeper references to: C language, streams. I like your answer with the phrase “sends data to standard output”, since the answer from Reda does not mention this correctly ("it prints to stdout"). Also, the answer from Reda is more to the point, because I was interested in the process itself, what is responsible for the print() function, I was not interested in where the output destination can be specified

Comment: But anyway, now your answer is indexed in Google. If I forget about this, I can find the answer faster! Thank you very much

Comment: thank you too, Our friend’s answer actually mentioned the deeper part. by the way I asked about any problems not because of that but because someone disliked my answer. thank you for your question firstly and also for your kindly way, Have a nice time